# How to make web authentication

Tags: php, http

I have a problem. HTTP authentication doesn't allow me as a user with right password and username on my website. I mean It still popups and asking me for credentials. Where I did mistake in code or should I check something else ? Sorry my english is pretty bad. Thank you very much.

CODE:

```
<?php
   $username='xxx';
   $password='xxx_XXX';
   if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) || !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])
    || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $username || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $password){
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Website"');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: You got the unauthorized part but you're missing the else part for the authorized part. How do you expect it to run?

Comment: You only have code for not authorizing a user. Either you've accidentally left out the rest (in which case we need to see it) or you haven't added it altogether.

Comment: Yes It work when I hit cancel it stops.

Comment: @Jonast92 exit works just fine like that, it's not a method, it's a built in, they've got pretty strange behaviour.

Comment: @scragar Always learning something new (even though I find it nasty).

Comment: I still don't get it what is wrong with this code

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your (posted) code. Are you running this on your own machine, or hosted service?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Then Why after i enter my credentials and hit enter It keeps poping up

Comment: I don't know. Again, are you running this on your own machine, or hosted service? Is it Windows? Unix?

Comment: @Fred-ii-On hosted service, I tried on localhost xx weeks ago and It works fine.

Comment: What version of PHP is the server running?

Comment: Your host may be blocking something, it's hard for me to say. I suggest you contact them about it, see what they say and send them a copy of the code you're trying to run. I've tested this on both Windows and Unix, no problem, both on hosted services.

Answer (score 0):

Relegate this to your Webserver responsibilities using a htaccess (apache assumed)

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/protected">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authentication Required"
  AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
  Require valid-user

  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then create the htauth file with:
    htpasswd -c /etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd user1
    htpasswd /etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd user2

Seems like a better tool unless you are doing a fully functional login website - but I think your code might need to mature before that ;-)